# How to extract links from a Wikipedia page summary?

Tags: python, wikipedia-api

I want to extract links from summary/abstract of Wikipedia pages in order to compare differences in language versions. However, I've only found sample coding to extract all links from the articles (like the one bellow). How could I manage to extract only from this section?

```
wikipedia.page("name of the page").links
```

Comment: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot/Overview might be worth looking into as well

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code,

```py
  @property
  def links(self):
    '''
    List of titles of Wikipedia page links on a page.
    .. note:: Only includes articles from namespace 0, meaning no Category, User talk, or other meta-Wikipedia pages.
    '''

    if not getattr(self, '_links', False):
      self._links = [
        link['title']
        for link in self.__continued_query({
          'prop': 'links',
          'plnamespace': 0,
          'pllimit': 'max'
        })
      ]

    return self._links
```

and the [API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Links#API_documentation), it would appear that changing the `plnamespace` parameter should do it.

Comment: Thank you! I'm still not sure where in this code I should identify from which page and section the links are to be extracted. Could you point?

Comment: @py_newie it would be in that plnamespace. You would change it from 0 to whatever namespaces you need

Comment: Can you please let me know what would be the namespace value for overview/summary/abstract section of a wikipedia page ?